# I have a problem with react and firestore database

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I dont know why but basically React is rendering only a single document but i m fetching a whole collection from the firestore database. Here is my code that fetch the data to the firestore database and render it on the page :

```
import BlogPres from "../components/BlogPres";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import db from "../firebase";
import { onSnapshot, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

const BlogsPres = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

  const loadDocs = () => {
    const colRef = collection(db, "blogs");

    onSnapshot(colRef, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        setBlogs([...blogs, { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }]);
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadDocs();
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      {blogs.map((blog) => (
        <BlogPres title={blog.title} author={blog.author} key={blog.id} />
      ))}
    </main>
  );
};

export default BlogsPres;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  setBlogs([...blogs, doc.data()]);
});
```

Everytime through this loop, you are wiping out the changes you did on the previous time. So if `blogs` is an empty array, you first set state with empty array + the first doc. Then you overwrite it with empty array + the second doc. In the end, the only one that will stick is empty array + the last doc.

You can either use the function form of set state, so you get passed in the latest version of the array:

```
setBlogs(prev => [...prev, doc.data()]);
```

Or better yet, just set state once with the full array:

```
onSnapshot(colRef, (snapshot) => {
  const newBlogs = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  setBlogs(newBlogs);
});
```